# Can Lion be configured to use the three finger drag gesture anywhere in the window?

Tags: macos, window-manager, multi-touch

With the proper gesture enabled, Lion allows using a three-finger drag to move a window. However, it only does this when the pointer is over the title bar; gesturing anywhere else in the window does a text highlight instead. Is there a hidden configuration or a hack that would allow three-finger window moving from anywhere inside the window's bounds? Thanks!

Comment: Not posting this as an answer because it doesn't actually work, but on the right path: BetterTouchTool allows you to set a modifier key combination that allows you to drag a window from anywhere. Click the *Advanced* option, then under the *Action Settings* area, *Window Moving & Resizing* tab, you can choose which modifier keys to use for such dragging. Unfortunately there's no way in BTT to set three-finger-movement to press those keys, but it may be that there's another utility out there that will. BetterTouchTool: http://www.boastr.de/ (it allows for all kinds of cool gesture stuff, too)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three-finger drag isn't a gesture for "move the window"; it's a gesture for "click and drag." While there might (now or someday) be third-party software that could accomplish your desired behavior, it falls beyond the scope of a simple hidden preference.